# How to uniquely identify a socket with Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, sockets

TLDR; How to identify sockets in event based programming model.

I am just starting up with node.js , in the past i have done most of my coding 
part in C++ and PHP sockets() so node.js is something extremely new to me.

In c++ to identify a socket we could have done something like writing a main socket say server to listen for new connections and changes, and then handling those connections accordingly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are looking for actual sockets and not socket.io, they do exist.

But as stated, Node.js and Javascript use an event-based programming model, so you create a (TCP) socket, listen on an IP:port (similar to bind), then accept connection events which pass a Javascript object representing the connection.

From this you can get the FD or another identifier, but this object is also a long-lived object that you can store an identifier on if you wish (this is what socket.io does).

```
var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(conn) {
  conn.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  conn.on('data', function(data) {
    conn.write('ID: '+conn.id);
  });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thats what i was looking for :D .. tys Tim CHEERS! . i found it laters reading the node.js manual for hours. but finally i found it and morever using javaScript these sockets can be handled as custom objects say users ;) . by the same way u illustrated. (by adding more properties then just ID :) .. ) cheers and thank you for help :)

Comment: See [another answer below concerning the **dangerous** use of `Math.random` at this point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17146037/2477364) (i.e. **don't do it like in the above example**). However, as long as the ID is only used on the serverside, I don't see a reason for not simply counting up a number and using that. There is no advantage for anyone to be able to guess the next ID (apart from the fact that noone knows the next ID, unless they have access to internal memory). Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why it's still the best answer? Using Random with IDs? Bad bad bad!

Comment: It was meant to be an example, not the ultimate way to generate a unique id. I don't know how to recommend a different answer be the accepted one, I think the original person asking the question needs to do that.

I do, however, consider the answer below to be superior to mine.

Comment: This does not work in TypeScript, at least not easily.

Answer (score 13):

Timothy's approach is good, the only thing to mention - Math.random() may cause id's duplication. So the chance it will generate the same random number is really tiny, but it could happen. So I'd recommend you to use dylang's module - [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid):

```
var shortid = require('shortid');
var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(conn) {
  conn.id = shortid.generate();
  conn.on('data', function(data) {
    conn.write('ID: '+conn.id);
  });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

So in that case you can be sure that no id duplications will occur.

Comment: Of course, consider it a stand in for however you want to generate your unique id. UUID's would be another good option.

Comment: shortid is good. But sometimes we just need integer IDs to reduce transmission traffic.

Comment: In that case I'd probably use a storage (like redis), to store the last id generated. Whenever an incoming connections occurs - identify it with that id, and bump it in redis by 1.

Comment: From the README: shortid is deprecated, because the architecture is unsafe. we instead recommend Nano ID, which has the advantage of also being significantly faster than shortid

Answer (score 6):

in **typescript**:

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import net from 'net';
class Socket extends net.Socket {
  id?: string;
}

const server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', (conn) => {
  conn.id = uuidv4();
  conn.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(conn.id);
  });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

you need to add `id` first;

Answer (score 1):

> In c++ to identify a socket we could have done something like writing
>   a main socket say server to listen for new connections and then
>   handling those connections accordingly.but so far i havent found
>   anything like that in node.js . (the berkeley socket model) Does it
>   even exist in node.js .. if not i am going back to my C++ :$

You should go back, because [JavaScript is a prototype-based, object-oriented scripting language that is dynamic, weakly typed and has first-class functions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) They are both completely different languages and you will have to have a different mindset to write clean JavaScript code.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Migrating-0.6-to-0.7

> ### Session ID
>
> If you made use of the sessionId property of socket in v0.6, this is now simply **.id.**
>
> ```
> // v0.6.x
> var sid = socket.sessionId;
>
> // v0.7.x
> var sid = socket.id;
> ```

Comment: sir, JavaScript is not a new thing for me i have used it for a lot of projects the client side of the project is fully writen on JavaScript ( i have written a 3d rendering engine & a raytracer in JavaScript using C++ background ) so i can handle the load of migrating. Thanks for your advice , i already found the solution out and server is pretty much done now . :)

Comment: @Darkyen okay very good. I thought you wanted JavaScript to look like C++, but I though wrong ...

Comment: ^_^ i like JavaScript more then C++ because of its freedom with code. but C++ has different benifits :) . I will give ya credits on the project website for helping ^_^ .

Answer (score 1):

if you found this question by looking for `socket.io` unique ids that you can use to differentiate between sockets on the client-side (just like i did), then here is a very simple answer:

```
var id = 0; //initial id value
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    var my_id = id; //my_id = value for this exact socket connection
    id++; //increment global id for further connnections

    socket.broadcast.emit("user_connected", "user with id " + my_id + "connected");
}
```

on every new connection the `id` is incremented on the serverside. this guarantees a unique id.
I use this method for finding out where a broadcast came from on the clientside and saving data from concurrent sockets.

for example:

**server-side**

```
var my_coords = {x : 2, y : -5};
socket.broadcast.emit("user_position", {id: my_id, coord: my_coords});
```

**client-side**

```
user = {};
socketio.on("user_position", function(data) {
    if(typeof user[data.id] === "undefined")
        user[data.id] = {};

    user[data.id]["x"] = data.coord.x;
    user[data.id]["y"] = data.coord.y;
});
```

Comment: Is this susceptible to race conditions?

Comment: Actually, according to https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/06/17/no-there-are-no-race-conditions-in-javascript/ I guess there shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

How to identify a client based on its socket id. Useful for private messaging and other stuff.

**Using socket.io v1.4.5**

client side:

```
var socketclientid = "john"; //should be the unique login id
var iosocket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000", {query: "name=john"});

var socketmsg = JSON.stringify({
  type: "private messaging",
  to: "doe",
  message: "whats up!"
});                        
iosocket.send(socketmsg);
```

server side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var sessionid = socket.id;
  var name = socket.handshake.query['name'];
  //store both data in json object and put in array or something

socket.on('message', function(msg){
  var thesessionid = socket.id;      
  var name = ???? //do lookup in the user array using the sessionid
  console.log("Message receive from: " + name);

  var msgobject = JSON.parse(msg);
  var msgtype = msgobject.type;
  var msgto = msgobject.to;
  var themessage = msgobject.message;

  //do something with the msg
  //john want to send private msg to doe
  var doesocketid = ???? //use socket id lookup for msgto in the array
                         //doe must be online
  //send to doe only
  if (msgtype == "private messaging") 
     socket.to(doesocketid).emit('message', 'themessage');

});
```

Comment: looking up for the 'name' and 'socket Id' in the arrays would drag your server to world's end when there will be millions-billions of user online.... this approach wouldn't work in real time.

Comment: That is just to show how to do priivate messaging. To know if the user is active or not. One can just use db storing active id in db and query if the recipient still active or not. Do you have any suggestion on how to maintain active client socket? Write it down man instead of just downvoting. We are all here to learn.

Comment: Also in the comment i wrote put in array or something. Get it? Or something means thousands of ways to do it

Comment: Seems you are a little bit pissed off n yelling .... calm down boy ... though downvoted coz your post is suggesting a malpractice. Okay ?

Comment: People here are not for learning only but to learn best practices exactly and a post giving suggestions with ambiguous/malpractices will not help them. For learning purposes, there are hell lots of blogs and sites.... go there.

Comment: What malpractice, i said put your suggestion on how to keep track of all the active socket ids so that the broadcast can be done or private messaging can be done. This is socket we are talking about. Sender and receiver need to keep track. If you think you are intelligent enough gives your suggestion put out a code instead of calling people boy or downvote people without giving constructive critism. What do you think i am black and a slave and want to call me boy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144631/discussion-between-shivam-and-jumper-rbk).

Answer (score 0):

mmmm, i don't really get what you're looking for but socket-programming with node.js (and socket.io) is really straight forward. take a look at some examples on the [socket.io homepage](http://socket.io/#how-to-use):

```
// note, io.listen() will create a http server for you
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  io.sockets.emit('this', { will: 'be received by everyone connected'});

  socket.on('private message', function (from, msg) {
    console.log('I received a private message by ', from, ' saying ', msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    sockets.emit('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

on connecting to the server, every socket get an unique id with which you can identify it later on.

hope this helps!?
cheers

Comment: Thank you.. sorry coming from BSD Socket background slightly infers vision when accepting new technologies.. i am too used too of the socket_select( ) or selector.wait() or sockets.select(); functions in C++ (additional lib's and php core sockets thanks for your help :D i got it now i wotn use socket.io though as i can write the parts of it that i need myself :D ) cheers!