# Assigning WebSocket and net.Socket with unique id

Tags: node.js, typescript, sockets, websocket

I aspire to assign Websockets and net.Sockets with unique identifiers, so when a message is received, the client is identified by the identifier attached to the socket.

**Previous research:**

*For Websocket:*

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364243/websocketserver-node-js-how-to-differentiate-clients) and [this](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/859), the following is requires:

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
   ws.id = uuid.v4(); // This is the relevant line of code
   ws.on('message', (msg: string) => {
   ...
   }
});
```

*For net.Socket:*

Quite the same - according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805432/how-to-uniquely-identify-a-socket-with-node-js), the following is required:

```
var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(conn) {
    conn.id = uuid.v4(); // This is the relevant line of code
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
    ...
    });
});
```

**The problem**

The error *"Property 'id' does not exist on type 'WebSocket' [or 'Socket' accordingly]"* during compilation. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type) explains why.

**Optional Solution #1: Cast to any**

The update net.Socket code will be:

```
var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(conn) {
    (conn as any).id = uuid.v4();
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Session id:' + (conn as any).id);
    });
});
```

*The problem:* It doesn't seem like good practice to me. I don't have references for why except for a hunch for now.

**Optional Solution #2: Use a local variable [seems like a better option]**

The update net.Socket code will be:

```
var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(conn) {
    const id: string = uuid.v4();
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Session id:' + id);
    });
});
```

After some experiencing, it seems to work properly.

**So - the questions:**

1. **In optional solution #2**: is it guaranteed that the id variable will always be available in this scope? In other words: is this solution valid? for both net.Socket & Websocket? Or is there something that I'm missing?
2. **In general**: Is there additional identifiers (perhaps built in identifiers in WebSocket and net.Socket) that can be used instead?

[*Typescript version:* 3.2.4].

Comment: for 1, it's valid solution, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of a field that already exists for that.

If you can keep the socket id in a local variable like you do in option 2, that's what I'd do. **I generally prefer to avoid adding arbitrary fields to objects.** However, sometimes you want the entirety of your application to be able to access the additional piece of data, and **in those cases using a local variable won't work.**

#### Adding a custom field

Instead of using a type assertion to `any`, you could add a file to your project that contains this:

```
declare module "net" {
    interface Socket {
        id: string;
    }
}
```

This is augmenting the `net.Socket` interface to add an `id` field which is a string. **This is a bit neater than a type assertion because the type assertion would let typos go through (e.g. `(conn as any).ids`).** I used your code, removed the type assertion and added the above in a file named `externals.d.ts` that I put next to the `.ts` file that contains your code. `tsc` stopped complaining about the field. Note that you don't need to import this file or refer to it in any way. You must just have a `tsconfig.json` that picks it up along with the rest of your source. By default, it would be picked up due to the `.d.ts` extension.

In the past I've used type assertions and interface augmentation to add arbitrary fields to DOM nodes, and it worked just fine. However, when I did that, I used field names that were *very singular*, meaning that there was a very low chance of a clash with other libraries that might want to add their own fields. Your field name is `id`. **I'd be worried about name clashes with other libraries that decide they want to keep track of sockets and add their own `id` field to a socket.**

#### Using `WeakMap`

There's another method you can use. You could setup a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) that associates the socket with the id. Here's an illustration. You could have a module `socket-map` that just exports a map that maps sockets to strings:

```
import * as net from "net";

export const socketMap = new WeakMap<net.Socket, string>();
```

And then you'd store the socket with the id when you obtain the socket:

```
import * as net from "net";
import * as uuid from "uuid";
import { socketMap } from "./socket-map";

var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(conn) {
    const id = uuid.v4();
    socketMap.set(conn, id); // You store the socket into the map.
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Session id:' + (conn as any).id);
    });
});
```

Then later, in another module, you could get the id back with:

```
import * as net from "net";
import { socketMap } from "./socket-map";

export function foo(conn: net.Socket) {
  const id = socketMap.get(conn);
}
```

Here I've just associated the socket with an id string, but you could have any structure you want in the values of the `WeakMap`. It could be an object that contains a whole slew of information besides an id.

The reason to use `WeakMap` is while the keys of a `WeakMap` object contain references to objects, these references *do not count* as far as garbage collection goes. So if your application is done with a socket and no longer references it anywhere than a `WeakMap`, the reference present in the `WeakMap` will still allow the socket to be collected by the garbage collector.